# VSCode integrated terminal not launching with proper settings

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, anaconda, miniconda

When I launch VSCode, I have the following JSON in my settings.json file which determines how the default integrated terminal should launch:

```
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "-ExecutionPolicy",
        "ByPass",
        "-NoExit",
        "-Command",
        "C:\\Miniconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1",
        ";conda activate 'C:\\Miniconda3'"
    ],
```

As expected, the *default* integrated terminal does use those shell arguments as it launches. However, I also have the Python extension installed, and I do a lot of Python debugging. When I attempt to debug a Python file, I have the following launch.json defined:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
```

As you see, the Python extension should use the integrated terminal when I attempt to debug a script. When I click the "Start Debugging" button in the user interface, it launches a *second* integrated terminal, but the *second* one which is launched does *not* use the above shell arguments which I defined in settings.json, and I need it to do so.

Anyone know how I can get VSCode to use the integrated terminal shell arguments that I have defined in settings.json when the Python extension launches its own integrated terminal? Or is there any way to have the Python extension use the pre-existing instance of the integrated terminal rather than launching a new instance that doesn't use those shell arguments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you **run python file in Terminal**, the terminal will be displayed as **python** type:
[image]
when you click **Start Debugging**, there will be a new terminal which type is **Python Debug Console** shown:
[image]
So this explains your question:

> When I click the "Start Debugging" button in the user interface, it launches a second integrated terminal

Also, about debug, configurations should be added in the `launch.json` and the setting about terminal you can keep it in the attributes **args**. Please refer to [debug](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) and [debug-args](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options). Putting the powershell settings in the `settings.json` has no effect on debug integrated terminal. That's why you found:

> the second one which is launched does not use the above shell arguments which I defined in settings.json

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really answer the question. As you noted, you can provide "args" in launch.json, but those are arguments for the program that is about to debugged, not arguments for launching the shell itself. Arguments for launching the shell itself are found in "terminal.integrated.shellArgs" in settings.json, and I definitely consider it a bug if I specify in "launch.json" that I want to use the "integratedTerminal", and then it doesn't use the "terminal.integrated.shellArgs" that I've defined in settings.json.

Comment: because debugging looks for settings in launch.json, not the settings.json

Comment: ehh... yes but no. If you define “integratedTerminal” as your desired shell in launch.json, it still has to go to settings.json to find out what the integratedTerminal is and how to launch it, because settings.json is where you define the integratedTerminal.

Comment: Oops! i thought i misunderstood your question,i'm sorry for that. I put the "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows" in settings.json, like you can see the screenshots in my answer, both of them using the same python.exe which defined in user setting.json. have you met this issue before? have your tried to reset vscode by deleting everything between the two curly braces in User settings.json or reinstalling vscode?